# A C(B)-module structure on the function algebra of the total space of a vector bunlde $\pi:V \to B$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, vector-bundles, modules, topological-manifolds

For a continuous vector bundle $\pi:V \to B$  vector bundle over a  compact Hausdorff space $B$, and $C(B)$, $C(V)$ the continuous complex valued functions on $B$ and $V$ respectively, we can give  $C(V)$ the structure of a $C(B)$ module as follows: For $f \in C(B)$, $g \in C(V)$, and $v \in V$, define 
$$
(f\triangleright g)(v) := f(\pi(v))g(v).
$$
What can we say about the structure of $C(V)$ as a $C(B)$-module?

Comment: What is $F$? If it's supposed to be $V$, look up the Serre-Swan theorem. Loosely speaking $C(V)$ should behave like Sym of the module of sections of the bundle, which is a finitely generated projective module.

Comment: Yes $F=V$, it is fixed now.

Comment: I know the Swan--Serre theorem, but can't see why taking Sym (which I guess is the symmetric tensor algebra) gives the continuous functions on the total space.

Comment: Consider first the case of a trivial bundle, so $V = \mathbb{R}^n \times B$, so that $C(V) = C(\mathbb{R}^n) \otimes C(B)$ where $\otimes$ is a suitably completed tensor product. Meanwhile the module of sections is $\mathbb{R}^n \otimes C(B) = C(B)^n$. The process of passing from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $C(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is loosely speaking (hence the caveat!) analogous to taking Sym; in algebraic geometry it's exactly taking Sym (of the dual) and here more completing is required.

Comment: This is really nice! It's more than I hoped was true. Could you give a reference for the algebraic geometry proof that taking Sym of the sections gives the total function algebra please.